# Uncaught SyntaxError passing multiple values to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call a function, but am running into some struggles with properly escaping the values and passing it properly. I currently have:

```
function selectdone(sel, title_id, status_type) {
...
}

$(function() {


$("td.status-updates").click(function() {
    if ($(this).find('#sel').length == 0) {
        var before = $(this).text();
        var title_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        var status_type = $(this).attr('class');
        $(this).html("<select id='sel' 
            onchange='selectdone(this," + title_id + "," + status_type +");'...
                                                <option>NS</option></select>");
    }

});
```

The error I keep getting from this is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`.

However, if I pass it as `'selectdone(this," + title_id + ");...` it works, but if I try and pass three it raises that error.

Note: there are spaces in the `status_type` variable (multiple classes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To repeat myself from your last question:

```
$(this).html($("<select/>", {
  id: 'sel',
  change: function() {
    selectdone(this, title_id, status_type);
  }
}).append($("<option/>", { text: "NS" })));
```

Also, to get the "class", it'd probably be better to use ".prop()":

```
var status_type = $(this).prop('className');
```

It's "className" as a property. Post jQuery 1.6, it's pretty rare that you'd really want ".attr()" and not ".prop()".

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has great built-in tools for handling events and manipulating the DOM; I suggest you use those.

```
$("td.status-updates").click(function() {
    if ($(this).find('#sel').length == 0) {
        var before = $(this).text();
        var title_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        var status_type = $(this).attr('class');
        $(this).empty().append(
            $('<select>').prop('id', 'sel')
            .on({
                change: function() {
                    selectdone(this, title_id, status_type);
                }
            })
            .append($('<option>').text('NS'))
        );
    }
});
```

[Relevant blog post](http://minitechme.blogspot.ca/2012/01/stop-using-strings-for-html-and-embrace.html)